# .bind animationend run on other function

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to detect when the CSS animation finishes to remove a class,
but when I use .bind animation ends it fires even on the other function. Heres the complete code https://jsfiddle.net/mg4t9cnt/1/
How to make it only run on one function

```
function hide_content(){
  $('.sidebar').removeClass('sidebar-show');
  $('.sidebar').on('animationend oAnimationEnd',function(event) {
   // only run on this function
   alert('hide content');
   });
    } 
function show_content(){
    $('.single-page').addClass('hidden');
  if(!$('.sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-show')){
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('hidden').addClass('sidebar-show');
  }

}

.sidebar{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:calc(100% - 500px);
  width: 500px;
  background: green;
  animation: slideright 1s forwards;
}

.sidebar-show{
  animation: slidesleft 1s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well i found the solution https://jsfiddle.net/mg4t9cnt/3/

```
function show_content(){
    $(".sidebar").off( "animationend oAnimationEnd" );
    $('.single-page').addClass('hidden');
  if(!$('.sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-show')){
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('hidden').addClass('sidebar-show');
  }
}
```

if you guys have another solution, please share it